# How to start an object containing a timer in a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, garbage-collection

How to start running an object containing a timer in a new thread?

I have the below code that I should probably change it:

```
    class MemoryCleaner : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly static MemoryCleaner Instance = new MemoryCleaner();

        private readonly Timer _memoryWatcher = new Timer(15 * 1000);

        public Timer MemoryWatcher
        {
            get
            {
                return this._memoryWatcher;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _memoryWatcher.Elapsed -= memoryWatcher_Elapsed;
            this._memoryWatcher.Stop();
        }

        private void memoryWatcher_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            var megaBytes = currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize64 / (1024 * 1024);
            if (megaBytes > 100)
            {
                // force an immediate garbage collection to free some unused memory quickly; this is an expensive process!
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        internal static void Start()
        {
            // this should be created in a new thread
            Instance.MemoryWatcher.Elapsed += Instance.memoryWatcher_Elapsed;
            Instance.MemoryWatcher.Start();
            GC.KeepAlive(Instance);
        }

        internal static void Stop()
        {
Instance.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I'd like to use it like:

```
MemoryCleaner.Start();
// my memory thirsty code which generates so much garbage, e.g. downloads a document then disposes it.
MemoryCleaner.Stop();
```

What it should do is that I should create a new thread then on that thread it should create a new instance of the MemoryCleaner object and start that object.

How would that be possible to do that?

Some background info:
Basically, what the code should do is that it should checke the memory used by the main process every 15 seconds and forces the garbage collection if memory usage exceeds 100MB since so many garbage will be created.

Hope the question is clear.

Thanks,

Comment: If your app genuinely uses >100MB, forcing a GC every 15 seconds is only going to make things worse, by **keeping the 100MB paged in**, which is the opposite of what you want (allow the OS to page it out when it's not used thus freeing up physical RAM).

Comment: You do not  'run' or 'start' an object.

Comment: Collecting the garbages over 100MB, makes the GC to Keep the 100MB paged in? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` it doesn't much matter which thread you create it on - unless you specify a synchronization object, the timer will fire on a thread-pool thread anyway. Why would you want to create a thread just for the creation part?

(I'm not at all sure that all of this is a good idea anyway, but that's a separate matter... You should also consider whether making a singleton implementation implement `IDisposable` is really sensible.)

Comment: Thank you Jon. The reason I wanted it to run on a separate thread is that the elapse doesn't work in my code. I don't know why. I tried a simple app but couldn't reproduce the issue and the elapse was working fine. Not sure what's causing this that my prod app makes the elapse not to work.

Comment: @TheLight: I would concentrate on diagnosing the difference rather than just putting something on a different thread.

Comment: My app uses heavy multithreading so if I can run the MemoryCleaner completely on a separate thread (that won't be shared with any other code) then it should resolve the issue. I think the reason is that when the timer elapses it waits until the thread pool has at least 1 available thread so it can't find it and waits until one becomes available again.

Comment: @TheLight: After you've started the timer, it will kick in on thread-pool threads. You could start a separate thread *just* for this (and sleep between GCs) but that's a different matter. I still think diagnosis of why something which *should* work doesn't work is worthwhile.